# how to get through 'Future<List<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>> and get data

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, android-studio

I have a list of type `'Future<List<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>>`
that looks like this,

```
var postlist = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('posts').orderBy("datePublished", descending: true).where('uid', whereIn: theUserData['following']).snapshots().toList();
```

and i want it to go through post list and get data, how? and thank you in advance!! <3

Comment: To get the data from a Future, you should either use `async & await` or use `then {...}` on the Future itself.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you get an error when you equal it to variable. I think you should use as List<QuerySnapshot<Map<String,
dynamic>>> keyword or some things like that I don't sure right now but
Let's say I have a function
Future<List<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>> getDataFun(){...}
So you can

```
List<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, 
dynamic>>> my data = await 
getDataFun() as List<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, 
dynamic>>>;
```